# Azure Logic App slice string from SQL database to email

Tags: azure, slice, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have a super simple logic app workflow that triggers when a new row is added to a  SQL Server Database and sends an email from a pre-specified address to another pre-specified address with variables from the row that was added.

I am having difficulty figuring out how to slice a string from the SQL data... One of the variables is called "invoiceDate" and I am able to refer to it in the logic app code view as "@{triggerBody()?['invoiceDate']} but an unable to perform slicing functions to it. I only want the first 9 characters of that variable to populate in the email and the slice function does not treat it like a variable.

[image: Logic App Designer Workflow]

Comment: solved with @{slice(triggerBody()?['invoiceDate'],0,10)}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `substring` expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#substring

This is a basic example ...

[image: Example]

The expression in the second step is ...

```
substring(variables('String'), 0, 9)
```

It's getting the first 9 characters of the `String` variable.

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Solved with different solutions, slicing the variable directly... @{slice(triggerBody()?['invoiceDate'],0,10)}